# How to include .js and .css files inside the res/ folder into the build dependency on eclipse for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I keep a couple of .css and .js files inside the res/raw folder of my android project. These files are loaded from a WebView instance and are in this folder mainly due to the access path limitations in WebView.
But my problem is that Eclipse does not include the css and js files into the build dependencies of my project. If I only touch one of these files the build flow is not regenerating the application.   I did add the project/res folder to the the Java Build Path in the "source" tab but that didn't help.  (I run eclipse 3.6.2 on mac as downloaded - no customizations)
How can I include these files in the build flow ?

UPDATE:

1) moving to the asset folder does not resolve the issue  (changes to the css and js files are still not triggering a rebuild)

2) It actually seems like the modification of the js/css files has an impact on the 2nd build after the change.  Touching only those files will result in a complete  build after hitting the build button twice  - Anyone else seen this ?

UPDATE 2:

1) I observer this only on MAC, the same version of eclipse works flawlessly on PC.

UPDATE 3:

1) This is only an issue when using an external editor for the files, once I switched to the   Text view inside Eclipse, the rebuild happens correctly.

Comment: Might help to look at how PhoneGap gets around this. They store .html, .js, .css files in /assets/www, though I'm not sure how/if that changes build process.

Comment: Are you saying that if you edit any of these files, it doesn't trigger an automatic rebuild? If so, it appears to be a common eclipse bug for certain resources. After editing some resources, I go to a .java class file, delete a character then retype it then go to Save All to trigger the rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a clean workaround, but switching to the internal editor (regular TextView for all the js and html files) solved the problem partially. As long as I stay within the eclipse environment this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Resources such as these are better off in the `assets/` directory and you should use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) in order to read them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: I think that's a good proposal  (moved all to  assets/www and set the loadbaseurl to  file:///android_asset/www).  But it did not solve the problem..   A change to the css/js files is still not picked up for rebuild.